# Rendered animation plays faster than not rendered

Tags: animation

I just rendered the animation of my project and saw it for the first time. The problem is that the rendered animation plays faster than not rendered. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Depending on how complex your scene is, your pc takes noticable time in the viewport to compute it

Comment: How could this be possible?

Comment: @Yash the playback frame rate in preview animation will depend on many things, mostly on the complexity of the scene and the computing power available. It is very unlikely that you will get realtime playback when previewing. Most likely the playback during preview will be slower. If you need to assess the animation in real time render using openGL to get a sense of what the final product will be.

Comment: @cegaton I should really browse for OpenGL, I heard it many times here, but didn't know what it is!

Answer (score 3):

When you talk about a "rendered animation" I suppose you're talking about the video result in FFMEPG format or else, and not what you see in *Rendered* or *Object* mode in your 3D view. In your 3D scene, in *Solid* mode, if you have a heavy scene with a lot of objects, it won't be able to play 24 images per seconds. If you want to have an idea of what is the real speed you need to go in the *Timeline* window > *Playback* menu, and enable *Frame Dropping* option. It will respect the real speed but at the price of some frame droppings.